# How to colour grouped barplot by group, not by conditon in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple dataframe and would like to create a grouped barplot with x axis as "decade" and y as "rate" and separate bars for "condition", but with different colours for different decades.

```
df <- data.frame (decade  = c("1970", "1970","1980", "1980","1990","1990","2000","2000"),
              condition = c("Yes", "No", "Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No"),
              rate = c(60,34,50,25,24,12,9,5))
```

I have tried the following but it gives color based on fill conitions, the color for the decade does not display

```
ggplot(df,aes(y=rate,x=decade,fill=condition,color=decade))+
geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")
```

[image]

What I would like is something like this, is this possible in ggplot or other graphical packages in R?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use just change the `fill` option to `decade`, it should do the trick.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame (decade  = c("1970", "1970","1980", "1980","1990","1990","2000","2000"),
                  condition = c("Yes", "No", "Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No"),
                  rate = c(60,34,50,25,24,12,9,5))

ggplot(df,aes(y=rate,x=decade,fill=decade,color=condition))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great, I will change it to alpha=condition to make the graph look nicer.